# Azure SQL Servers - Manage Backups - Long-term Retention Configurations not being saved

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to add a long-term retention configuration with monthly backups to my Azure SQL server database. Everything looks good but when I hit `Apply` the configuration is still not saved.

[image]

Confirmation:

[image]

After clicking `Yes` the dialog disappears but nothing is saved. I have tried to refresh the subscription and log in and out. I even tried Incognito to ensure that no plugin or cache was interfering. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by first selecting the database with the checkbox instead of clicking the table row. After selecting the checkbox I clicked on `Configure retention` in the `Configure policies` tab.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure

Comment: Terrible UI.  I spent an hour trying to figure out why it wouldn't save the policy.

Comment: @John81 I agree, really bad!